# Decode file input

Tags: python, encoding

I have a plain text file with this content:

```
Test: \u0410\u0412\u0422\u041e
```

I try to read that file in python and print the characters in unicode like this:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('b.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print line
```

Output:

```
Test: \u0410\u0412\u0422\u041e
```

I was expeting this text:

```
Test: ABTO
```

"Test" following the cyrilic word for STOP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990169/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-python-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ascii file with unicode escape sequence; of the form `\u0410...` we have to convert it to the form `\\u0410....` so that we can apply decode function as follows.

```
f = open('b','r')
for line in f:
    line.replace('\u','\\u')
    print line.decode('unicode-escape')
```