# Python: decode encoded string to utf-8 inside json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I've more then 1GB json file with encoded strings inside. For example:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "billing_type": {
        "id": "standard",
        "name": "\u0421\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442"
    },
    "area": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"
    }
}
```

How I can decode like this `\u041c\u043e` string inside my json file in my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [decode encoded JSON result in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346173/decode-encoded-json-result-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

if you use python3, just `import json` will help.

```
import json


result = json.loads(json_data)
print(result)
```

or python2, you should use `encode` method for each values (after check type first)

```
result = json.loads(json_data)

for k, v in result.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for dk, dv in v.items():
            print dk.encode("utf-8"), dv.encode("utf-8")
    else:
        print k.encode("utf-8"), v.encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = "\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"
data = data.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

This might be a solution.