# Convert 4 digit unicode escape to actual symbol

Tags: autoit

How can I convert a 4 digit unicode escape sequence to the actual symbol in AutoIt
e.g `"\u00a5" to "¥"`

Comment: How are you getting the escape sequence input? And where are you trying to output?

Comment: My autoIt code is called from a Python code. The AutoIt code runs as a subprocess.

Comment: I would do the conversion in Python first, and/or just [use a Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/0.51) for keyboard and mouse automation.

Comment: How can you do the same conversion in python?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/992314/391161).

Comment: It works for latin characters, but not for this symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this?

```
    #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $sText = ""
For $i = 256 To 2048
    $sText = $sText & ChrW($i) ; Or $sText &= ChrW($i) can be used as well.
Next
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Unicode chars 256 to 2048", $sText) ; Display the unicode characters between 256 to 2048.
```

or this :[Special chars in Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154487-specialcharactersviewer-v1010/#entry1115457)

or this:?

```
#include <WinAPI.au3>
Local $str = "My name is \u00a5"
Local $utfStr = Execute("'" & StringRegExpReplace($str, "(\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4}))", "' & ChrW(0x$2) & '") & "'")
Local $ansiStr = _WinAPI_WideCharToMultiByte($utfStr)
MsgBox(64, "Unicode2Ansi", $utfStr & @CRLF & $ansiStr)
Exit
```

Comment: I was looking for the third part that you have mentioned. It works. Thanks

Comment: The last solution does not work if there is a ' inside the string. You have to escape it before.

Comment: You can i.e. change the 3rd line to : Local $utfStr = Execute("'" & StringRegExpReplace(StringReplace($str,"'","''"), "(\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4}))", "' & ChrW(0x$2) & '") & "'") .