# convert escaped unicode sequence to human readable format

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I've been using this python code:

```
pattern = u'丨フ丨ノ一丨ノ丶フノ一ノ丨フ一一ノフフ丶'
result = [u'<span id="z_i_t2_bis" title="\u7ad6\u6298\u7ad6\u6487\u6a2a\u7ad6\u6487\u637a\u6298\u6487\u6a2a\u6487\u7ad6\u6298\u6a2a\u6a2a\u6487\u6298\u6298\u637a">\u4e28\u30d5\u4e28\u30ce\u4e00\u4e28\u30ce\u4e36\u30d5\u30ce\u4e00\u30ce\u4e28\u30d5\u4e00\u4e00\u30ce\u30d5\u30d5\u4e36</span>']

if pattern in result[0]:
    print('found')
```

But this is cumbersome and moreover doesn't really do what I want, which is to get the escaped gobbledygook back into something comprehensible, as in that pattern. Is there some simple unix tool or commnand to perform this task quickly and efficiently?

[seems that is one would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990169/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-python-string), but I tried it and it did not. i.e.,

```
result = "\u4e28\u30d5\u4e28\u30ce\u4e00\u4e28\u30ce\u4e36\u30d5\u30ce\u4e00\u30ce\u4e28\u30d5\u4e00\u4e00\u30ce\u30d5\u30d5\u4e36"

result.decode('utf-8')
```

which generated the error: `attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply `print(result)` then you'll get the "gobbledygook", because that's what Python uses when it gives you an unambiguous output as an element of a list or tuple. But if you print the string directly, `print(result[0])`, it will try to print the natural characters as they were intended.

If you want to convert the characters to utf-8 yourself, use `encode` rather than `decode`. `encode` converts a Unicode string to bytes, `decode` produces a Unicode string *from* bytes.